# Entregar JSON anidado en WebAPI .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

Necesito entregar un JSON que posee un TimelineItem donde cada timelineitem corresponde a un usuario.

Clase user

```
    public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Clase timelineitem

```
    public class TimelineItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

Mi get en la api

```
    // GET: api/TimelineItems
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<TimelineItem> GetTimelineItems()
    {
        return _context.TimelineItems;
    }
```

JSON que me entrega

```
[{"id":2,"content":"fsdaj fdsfa fsdjklafjlk fdjsaklfjsad fjdsklf  fdsjakl","title":"fjdskjfsdakl","user":null},{"id":3,"content":"fsdjk wqeui ietuw q tweti gj vcm v,cmv vmc,v c","title":"ureiwu","user":null},{"id":4,"content":"hola amigos del yu tub","title":"fdsfsda","user":null}]
```

Todos los usuarios me devuelven nulo.

Supongo que debería cambiar el modelo de TimelineItem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como en efecto debes modificar tu modelo TimelineItem ya que has definido una propiedad de navegación pero no has declarado UserId como atributo. Prueba esto:

```
public class TimelineItem
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Content { get; set; }
public string Title { get; set; }
public int UserId { get; set; }
public User User { get; set; }
}
```

Respondiendo a tu otra duda. El Usuario te sale como `null` porque EF no carga los datos correspondientes a él ya que no estas preguntando por `User` sino por `TimelineItem` por lo que EF se limita a ofrecerte sólo información referente a `TimelineItem`, esto es pensado con el fin de mejorar el rendimiento en las consultas a BD, esto se conoce como Lazy Loading o Carga Perezosa. Si quieres que tu Json muestre el `User` de cada `TimelineItem` debes hacer un `Include` en tu consulta LINQ ejemplo:

```
    // GET: api/TimelineItems
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<TimelineItem> GetTimelineItems()
    {
        return _context.TimelineItems.Include(t=>t.User);
    }
```

de esta forma tu Json te retorna un Objeto `User` para cada `TimelineItem` y puedes acceder a cualquier propiedad de él de la fomra `@model.user.xxx`. Espero te sea de ayuda

Comment: Me reconoce el UserID, pero el objeto user me lo sigue enviando vacio.

`[{"id":2,"content":"fsdaj fdsfa fsdjklafjlk fdjsaklfjsad fjdsklf  fdsjakl","title":"fjdskjfsdakl","userID":1,"user":null},{"id":3,"content":"fsdjk wqeui ietuw q tweti gj vcm v,cmv vmc,v c","title":"ureiwu","userID":2,"user":null},{"id":4,"content":"hola amigos del yu tub","title":"fdsfsda","userID":3,"user":null},{"id":5,"content":"este es el contenido","title":"este es el titulo","userID":5,"user":null}]`

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione de la siguiente manera, luego de seguir la recomendacion de Vicente Almea

Y agregar

```
public class TimelineItem
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Content { get; set; }
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public int UserId { get; set; }
   public User User { get; set; }
}
```

Fui a mi controlador y modifique el metodo get de la siguiente forma:

```
        // GET: api/TimelineItems
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<TimelineItem> GetTimelineItems()
    {
        foreach (TimelineItem item in _context.TimelineItems)
        {
            item.User = _context.Users.Find(item.UserID);
        }

        return _context.TimelineItems;
    }
```

Supongo que igual habría alguna manera de hacer el foreach como LINQ pero me funciono.

Comment: He modificado mi respuesta. Saludos